# Under what cases does a VSTS build produce an empty drop

Tags: c#, .net, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .Net (VS 2015) application that I manually build using VSTS. The build was successfully completed but no artifacts were generated. The agents/tasks used in this manual build are the NuGet tool installer, NuGet restore, Visual Studio build, publish build artifact.

Visual Studio Build parameters:

[image: VS Build]

Publish Build Artifact parameters:

[image: Publish Artifact]

Variables added:

[image: Variables]

End Result:

[image: No Drop Generated]

A similar structure should be produced as per my expectation:

[image: Expected Artifact Structure]

Comment: It would help if you could show us or tell something about the build definition. What are supposed to be the artifacts? How are you generating them, and how are you publishing them?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Question Updated.

Comment: which build agent are you using? Hosted? Hosted VS2017?

Comment: Also, have you run your build in debug mode? Set the `system.debug` variable to `true` and queue a new build. Check for warnings in the logs, specially in the `Build solution` task.

Comment: Hosted. system.debug was set to false.. Can you please explain what is the purpose of this.

Comment: Running the build in debug mode will give you more details when running your tasks, which could explain why the deployment package is not generated and/or published

Comment: Have you checked for warnings in the logs, in the "`Build solution`" task?

Comment: Also try `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\package.zip"` instead of `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

Answer (score 1):

Before the "Publish artifacts" task, you need to copy to the folder `a` in the agent the files you want they will be in the artifacts.

For example:

[image]

Now in your artifacts folder (`a` on the agent) will be your release output and in the Publish task it will be published as artifacts.

Comment: This is pure speculation - without knowing more details of the build, what are the artifacts and how they're generated it's impossible to know why the directory is empty

Comment: The asker wrote the steps: "I have used the NUGET package manager, VISUAL STUDIO build, publish artifact", so it's simple that the artifacts will be empty, he must copy the artifacts to the `a` folder before he publishes. I don't know which files he wants for artifacts, I brought an example, but I explained the process he needs to do.

Comment: Question Updated.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Basically this application generates an exe. So i am still researching on what exactly should constitute in the artifact.. Also i tried the copy files task and i did get a drop folder but it seems the whole source code was copied into the drop folder. So in my case should i just restrict the drop to an exe.. I am not at all sure.

Comment: @Salman In the Copy Filed task you have field "Content", you can define there to copy only the `exe` file.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Are the artifacts generated after using "Copy files" task same as without using it. It looks to me like if i give ** in Content it just copies the whole codebase. However i am not clear as to what should i exclude to get only those items which need to be published. Can u provide a useful resource as to what files are expected in dotnet build. Since i have many dotnet apps to build i badly need to undestand this.

Comment: @Salman I see now in your update that you have an argument `PacakgeLoaction` and you enter the variable for the artifacts folder, so you don't need the Copy Files task, in your `a` folder should be the `zip` file fo your web. can you share the logs from the Build task?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk can u specifically tell me what to look for in build task log

Comment: Check in the logs when the zip creation, in which location is created